# C# Windows Service Timer app config change in runtime

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, app-config

I'm making some Windows Services in c# and i need to read some variables from a config file like files and paths. I also have a variable that controls (it should) the timer interval. The problem is, every time a change data in the config file, that data is not fetched and, for example, if i change the file name i get an error saying that the file  does not exist (and i checked the name and the path) or if i change the time interval nothing happens. Can someone help me please?

```
System.Timers.Timer timer;
    CallWebServices call;
    int time;

    public Planview_SEB_Pervasive()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        call = new CallWebServices();
        startPervasive();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        call.InsertLog("PV/S&B Win Service", "Serviço parado", "");
    }

    private void startPervasive()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                //Vai buscar o tempo ao app.config
                time = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TimeElapsedInMinutes"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Em caso de falha ficam 5 minutos
                call.InsertLog("PV/S&B Win Service StartPervasive (time)", ex.Message, "");
                time = 5;
            }
            this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.AutoReset = true; //Necesário para que o srviço se repita
            timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * time; //Cálculo para minutos
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Elapsed);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            call.InsertLog("PV/S&B Win Service StartPervasive", ex.Message, "");
            OnStop();
        }
    }

    protected void Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TimeElapsedInMinutes"));
            StartProcess();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            call.InsertLog("PV/S&B Win Service Elapsed", ex.Message, "");
        }
    }

    private static void StartProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            string directory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WorkingDirectory");
            string file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FileToRun");


            //Execução dos processo (ficheiro)
            Process process = new Process();

            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directory;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = directory + @"\" + file;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `FileSystemWatcher` that monitors the directory where the app.config is stored in. When it is updated you will get an event in your application notifying you that something has changed. When that occurs you can reload the app.config and refresh your values.

Link: [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: I can give it a try but why can't i fetch the data in runtime? Better i fetch but why does it not work??